# How can I perform the same operation on all cells in a row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to calculate the cost of products based on the amount of products sold (in one row) and the cost of each item (in another row).

I have written a simple formula, but every time I add or remove columns, it must be manually adjusted.

```
=IF(COUNT(E4:AC4)>0,(E4*$E$3+F4*$F$3+G4*$G$3+H4*$H$3+I4*$I$3+J4*$J$3+K4*$K$3+L4*$L$3+M4*$M$3+N4*$N$3+O4*$O$3+P4*$P$3+Q4*$Q$3+R4*$R$3+S4*$S$3+T4*$T$3+U4*$U$3+V4*$V$3+W4*$W$3+X4*$X$3+Y4*$Y$3+Z4*$Z$3+AA4*$AA$3+AB4*$AB$3+AC4*$AC$29), "")
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please briefly describe what you formula does.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a problem best solved by [`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

Take the table

```
______|_$5_|_$7_|_$2_|_$3_|_$5_|__TOTAL__
-----------------------------------------
Bob   |    |  2 |    |  1 |    |     ?
-----------------------------------------
Alice |    |    |  2 |    |    |     ?
-----------------------------------------
Eve   |  1 |    |  1 |    |  3 |     ?
```

How do we solve the total cost for each row?

In the total column for Bob's row (2), simply invoking

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(B2:F2*B$1:F$1))
```

Will accurately give us his total cost; $7*2 + $3*1 = $17.

Specifically, `ARRAYFORMULA(B2:F2*B$1:F$1)` will give us a range composed of `B2*B1 | C2 * C1 | D2 * D1 ...`, which you could use e.g. in line below Bob's order to show the price breakdown by item. `SUM()` adds those numbers together. You could further add to this formula to add taxes, gratuity, shipping, service fees, etc.

Now that we have this formula, we can simply copy this down the column into each new row in the 'Total' column.

When a new column is inserted to the left, the formula will be automatically adjusted by the spreadsheet to be the new range.